# ".android" folder and "debug.keystore" file missing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, keytool, opensuse

am using Linux opensuse, eclipse helios package

i have to import google maps in my application for which i need an API key, so in order to get the api key i need to get the MD5 sum value which has to be got by running the debug.keystore file using keytool

but the problem is my whole ".android" folder is missing including debug.keystore file.but all the projects a re running smoothly,am able to find it in windows xp, but not in linux(opensuse)

if so what i must do in order to generate a new debug.keystore file???

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Navigate to the .android folder in your home directory `~/.android` (Linux,Mac OS) or `C:\Documents and Settings\[User Name]\.android` in Windows XP or `C:\Users\.android` in Windows Vista or Windows 7, and delete the `debug.keystore` file. Then go to eclipse and clean the project, this will create a new `debug.keystore` file with default validity period 365 days.

For Linux user: Delete your debug certificate (`debug.keystore` and `ddms.cfg`) under `~/.android/debug.keystore`

For Windows user: Delete your debug certificate (`debug.keystore` and `ddms.cfg`) under 
`C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\.android`

Comment: Thanks dude its i finally figured out what was the error i did in searching for it

friends if u are searching for debug.keystore file in any of the linux distribution make sure u have "show hidden file-> enabled" since by default the ".android" folder is hidden, dont forget to do this :-)

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you are developing in eclipse. select preferences-> android-> build-> default debug store or custom debug store, see path there and find debug.keystore.

Comment: Thanks dude its i finally figured out what was the error i did in searching for it

friends if u are searching for debug.keystore file in any of the linux distribution make sure u have "show hidden file-> enabled" since by default the ".android" folder is hidden, dont forget to do this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks dude its i finally figured out what was the error i did in searching for it

friends if u are searching for debug.keystore file in any of the linux distribution make sure u have "show hidden file-> enabled" since by default the ".android" folder is hidden, dont forget to do this :-)